# Jenkins doesn't wait Grunt serve command to be completed

Tags: shell, jenkins, gruntjs

I'm having an issue with my Jenkins job.

I'm doing a bunch of tests on my repository and to make these tests at some point I need to serve this repo locally. So I'm doing:

`grunt serve:dist &`

It seems though that Jenkins execute shell does not wait the command to finish and starts to run the next commands which unfortunately makes the job fail.

To overcome this I added a `sleep 100` after the above command to give time for the serve command to finish but that doesn't feel that good and clean.

Is there another cleaner way to wait for `grunt serve:dist &` to finish?

Comment: Why did you add that `&` at the end?

Comment: Check this answer @tkausl : http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86249 

So, though I want to let it run on the background I want it to complete before the next commands start running

Comment: Well if you do want to wait until it finishes, don't run it in the background.

Comment: the reason that I run it in the background is because I also want the server continue running so I can run somewhere my tests. Its like I want the best of both worlds, wait until its finished but let it run on the background. Does that make sense?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I also want the server continue running"?

Comment: `grunt serve` serves a server locally right? I need this to be running on the background so I can run my next commands somewhere (these next commands are my tests). So if there is not a server serving my website I can't test my website.